# CSS nth table wizardry

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to utilize the nth-child to get table 2 working. It needs to show only rows 11-20 in table 2 and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help?

Table 1 should show rows 1-10 – this is working
Table 2 should show rows 11-20 – this currently shows 11-end (I can’t get it to stop at 20)
Table 3 should show 21-30 – this is working

```
table.style1 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.style1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(n + 11) {
    display: none;
}

table.style2 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.style2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(-n + 10):nth-child(-n + 19) {
    display: none;
}

table.style3 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.style3 > tbody > tr:nth-child(-n + 20) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: can you please show your full code

Comment: please show the HTML

Comment: Also create a snippet to show your example.

Comment: You are wrong for `style2` `tr:nth-child(-n + 10):nth-child(-n + 19)`. Use `table.style2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(-n + 10), table.style2 > tobdy > tr:nth-child(n+21)` instead of.  @itodd, @andrewli's solutions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
table.style2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(-n + 10):nth-child(-n + 19) {
  display: none;
}
```

use:

```
table.style2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(-n + 10),
table.style2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(n + 21) {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked exactly as I wanted. Really appreciate the assist!

Answer (score 1):

You could do as following.
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/97g0wstu/11/)

```
table.style1 {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.style1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(n + 11) {
display: none;
}

table.style2 {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

> table.style2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(-n + 10), table.style2 > tobdy > tr:nth-child(n+21){
>              display: none;
>      }

```
table.style3 {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.style3 > tbody > tr:nth-child(-n + 20) {
display: none;
}
```